# Reference Error variable is not defined with ejs and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to send a variable from nodejs(expressjs) to html page with ejs. But i'm getting  ReferenceError: ...... variable is not defined error.

folder structure:

- node_modules
- src
- static-pages-server

  - static-pages-server.js
- views

  - pages

    - journey-analize-report.ejs
  - partials

journey-analize-report.ejs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        console.log('<%-currentCulture%>');
</script>
```

static-pages-server.js:

```
   const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const ejs = require('ejs');
    var path = require('path');
    var currentCulture;
    
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render("pages/journey-analize-report", {currentCulture:"Hello"});
});
```

Error:

```
 ReferenceError: D:\Project-UI\views\pages\journey-analize-report.ejs:46
            44|     <script type="text/javascript">
            45|         
         >> 46|         console.log('<%-currentCulture%>');
            47|   
        
        currentCulture is not defined
            at eval (eval at compile (D:\SeyirMobilNG-UI\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:662:12), <anonymous>:12:16)
            at journey-analize-report (D:\SeyirMobilNG-UI\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:692:17)
            at tryHandleCache (D:\SeyirMobilNG-UI\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:36)
            at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (D:\SeyirMobilNG-UI\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)
            at View.render (D:\SeyirMobilNG-UI\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
            at tryRender (D:\SeyirMobilNG-UI\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
            at Function.render (D:\SeyirMobilNG-UI\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
            at ServerResponse.render (D:\SeyirMobilNG-UI\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
            at D:\SeyirMobilNG-UI\static-page-server\static-pages-server.js:41:9
            at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\SeyirMobilNG-UI\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this syntax

```
<%= currentCulture %>
```

But you used

```
<%-currentCulture%>
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error =/

Comment: Maybe you need set a value for currentCulture, is it true?

Comment: I set value in another function. Also after your comment i tried to send inline value andit didn't work to. I edited js file in my question.